# How to merge two different Hyperledger Fabric Networks to a single network with two different channels

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have two different Blockchain networks with HLF 1.4.1 with two parties A and B and A and C each having its own genesis block and single channel with some data.

Is there any way to merge these two networks in to one network with A, B, C as organizations and their individual channels data between A->B and A->C in the merged network?

How the genesis block and the crypto can be configured in the case?

Answer (score 0):

The process of merging channels can be viewed as two.
First, there is a method of using an existing channel and a method of creating a new channel.

#### 1. use existing channels

This is a method of participating C organization in the channel between A<->B through configtxlator. 
See for details
[fabric-1.4/channel_update](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html) \

- Of course, B can participate in channel A<->C.

#### 2. create a new channel

Create a new channel for A<->B<->C to participate
This is exactly the same as the existing channel creation process.

---

#### All of the above methods require data porting.

In case 1, it is necessary to update the state of the channel between B<->C to the new channel A<->B<->C.
In case 2, it is necessary to update all existing two channel state data.

This process should be done separately according to your taste. You can do it manually, or you can develop and apply an automated script.

---

#### Genesis block?

The configtxlator result from step 1 is updated in the channel. Due to the data structure of the blockchain, the existing Genesis block (0th height) does not disappear, but new configuration(add other organization) of the channel itself is reflected in the form of a newly added update block.

In the case of step 2, a new genesis block is created because it is completely newly constructed.

---

#### Crypto?

In the case of the crypto configuration, the existing organization can be used as it is without changing separately.